# How to upgrade Ruby Bundle version in AWS Opsworks

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, ruby, opsworks, bundler

I have a project running on AWS Opsworks, which has current bundler version of ***1.5.3*** on ***Ruby 2.2.2***.

i want to upgrade the bundle version to ***1.17.3***

but when i try to do it i am getting this error

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/local/bin/gem install bundler -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.11.2" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
"bundle" from bundler conflicts with /usr/local/bin/bundle
---- End output of /usr/local/bin/gem install bundler -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.11.2" ----
Ran /usr/local/bin/gem install bundler -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.11.2" returned 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_bundler/recipes/default.rb

2:   gem_package "Installing Bundler #{node[:opsworks_bundler][:version]}" do
3:     gem_binary node[:dependencies][:gem_binary]
4:     retries 2
5:     package_name "bundler"
6:     action :install
7:     version node[:opsworks_bundler][:version]
8:     if Gem::Version.new(node[:opsworks_rubygems][:version]) > Gem::Version.new("2.6.14")
9:       options "--force"
10:     end
11:   end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_bundler/recipes/default.rb:2:in `from_file'

gem_package("Installing Bundler 1.11.2") do
provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
action [:install]
retries 0
retry_delay 2
package_name "bundler"
version "1.11.2"
cookbook_name "opsworks_bundler"
recipe_name "default"
gem_binary "/usr/local/bin/gem"
end



[2019-12-04T04:42:03+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2019-12-04T04:42:03+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2019-12-04T04:42:03+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2019-12-04T04:42:03+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-12-04T04:42:03+00:00] ERROR: gem_package[Installing Bundler 1.11.2] (opsworks_bundler::default line 2) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/local/bin/gem install bundler -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.11.2" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
"bundle" from bundler conflicts with /usr/local/bin/bundle
---- End output of /usr/local/bin/gem install bundler -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.11.2" ----
Ran /usr/local/bin/gem install bundler -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.11.2" returned 1
[2019-12-04T04:42:03+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

[image]

[image]

when i run `bundle -v` on the server i am getting bundler version as **1.5.3.** what ever i do i cannot change the bundle version from that.

```
root@hades:/srv/www/app_unicorn/current# which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem

root@hades:/srv/www/app_unicorn/current# which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

root@hades:/srv/www/app_unicorn/current# which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle

root@hades:/srv/www/app_unicorn/current# gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.9 (2016-03-30 patchlevel 490) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games

root@hades:/srv/www/app_unicorn/current# bundle env
Bundler 1.5.3
Ruby 2.1.9 (2016-03-30 patchlevel 490) [x86_64-linux]
Rubygems 2.2.2
GEM_HOME

Bundler settings
  path
    Set for your local app (/srv/www/app_unicorn/releases/20061825/.bundle/config): "/home/deploy/.bundler/app_unicorn"
  without
    Set for your local app (/srv/www/app_unicorn/releases/20061825/.bundle/config): "test:development"
  disable_shared_gems
    Set for your local app (/srv/www/app_unicorn/releases/20061825/.bundle/config): "1"
```

someone asked me to look into this issue. but i dont know what to do with this https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/536

how to add configuration in either the chef recipe  or anywhere else to update the bundle version ?

my cook book :- https://gist.github.com/nijeeshjoshy/90ef2dfc693c869205bad589ef1b0e23

[image]